# Users can't verify there account on peoplepods (open source cms)

Tags: php, email, content-management-system, verify

I have downloaded the latest version of the people pods (open source cms), but when new users sign up they do not receive verification email. More users have had the same problem and asked on the web developer's website, but received no answer. I have looked through the code but have not found where the problem can be. Anyone here who has a solution?

Project page: http://peoplepods.net

On google code: http://code.google.com/p/peoplepods/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that your PHP configuration is set up correctly to send email. Search for **mail** inside php.ini and you will see the settings there.

You can test this by using a simple email script:

```
<?php
var_dump(mail('your@email.com', 'subject goes here', 'Message body here...'));
?>
```

Save that as test.php on your server and load it in the browser. It should show you a boolean (true or false) depending on whether the email got sent or not. Regardless of whether this is true, it doesn't mean the email was sent though, so make sure you actually receive it too.

After you have verified this is working, check peoplepods to make sure it doesn't have any unsupported email headers in it's own mail function.

Comment: I get "bool(true)" when I run the script.

Comment: When I use your code and replace 'your@email.com' with my real email do I get "bool (true)" when I load it in my browser, but I get no email. The email appears to be sent but not received! When I send e-mails from peoplepods I also get information about the email was sent correctly  but nothing in my mailbox.

Comment: I have tested your code to different email addresses and it seems that if I enter an address to xxx@gmail.com or xxx@hotmail.com am I am not receiving any email (not even in spam). But if I fill in an email to xxx@yahoo.com will I receive a mail. Guess you're right about email headers. Tips on where / how I should change the email header in the code?

Comment: I'd be more inclined to say it was those email services blocking the emails. You aren't blacklisted are you? Have you got another server that you can test with?

Comment: The server from my hosting is blacklisted. Created a new account with the same provider but on a different server and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my web site. Users were not verifying their new accounts because verification emails kept going to their spam folders. I had to verify users manually for weeks.

**Reason:**
I discovered that emails were going to spam because spambots *thought* they looked *the same* as other emails sent from many other servers.

**Solution:** 
I edited all email templates to make them *different* from the others. The verification email template is located at:

> /peoplepods/themes/*your-theme-eg-default*/emails/welcome.php

I hope this helps.